# Java collection implementation with Linked List

Tags: java, collections, linked-list

How can I implement a collection using a linked list by extending the Abstract collection? I'd have to use the void remove method if Iterator, and implement this and the add and size methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Java doc for AbstractCollection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html) for more details:

> To implement an unmodifiable
>   collection, the programmer needs only
>   to extend this class and provide
>   implementations for the iterator and
>   size methods. (The iterator returned
>   by the iterator method must implement
>   hasNext and next.)
>
> To implement a modifiable collection,
>   the programmer must additionally
>   override this class's add method
>   (which otherwise throws an
>   UnsupportedOperationException), and
>   the iterator returned by the iterator
>   method must additionally implement its
>   remove method.

```
public abstract int size()

public abstract Iterator<E> iterator()
```

Iterator defines this methods:

```
boolean hasNext()

E next()

void remove()
```